# Better way to implement the Chat Bubble with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi I'm trying to implement the Custom Chat Bubble without GitHub library.

I have 5 swift files.

1. Custom UILabel
2. MyBubble as UITableViewCell + xib
3. SomeoneBubble as UITableViewCell + xib
4. TableViewController.

Here is my UILabel.swift

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ChattingBubble: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 10.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 10.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 16.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 16.0

    @IBInspectable var radius: CGFloat = 10
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))


        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth



    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
        var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
        return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
    }

}
```

And It is myBubble : UITableViewCell

```
class MyBubbleCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bubbleLbl: ChattingBubble!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventLbl: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code


        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 242.0 / 255.0, green: 242.0 / 255.0, blue: 242.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]
I think looks great but My problem is UITableViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        //define cell
        let myBubble = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyBubbleCell", for: indexPath) as! MyBubbleCell
        let someoneBubble = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SomeoneBubbleCell", for: indexPath) as! SomeoneBubbleCell

        let object = results[indexPath.row]

            //My Bubble
            if object.isMyBubble == true {
//LastCell will be shown "Time Label"
                if indexPath.row != (results.count - 1){
                    myBubble.eventLbl.isHidden = true
                    myBubble.bubbleLbl.text = object.messageTxt

                }else {

                    myBubble.bubbleLbl.text = object.messageTxt

//This code means waiting for notification from server. It just shown when enter the message... immediately 
                    if object.messageId == nil {
                        myBubble.eventLbl.isHidden = true
                        myBubble.bubbleLbl.text = object.messageTxt
                        myBubble.bubbleLbl.textColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.5)

                    //When received from server then shown the text    
                    }else {

                        myBubble.eventLbl.isHidden = false
                        myBubble.bubbleLbl.text = object.messageTxt
                        UIView.transition(with: myBubble.bubbleLbl, duration: 0.6, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { myBubble.bubbleLbl.textColor = .black }, completion: nil)

                        myBubble.eventLbl.text = object.msgDate

                    }


                }

                return myBubble

            //Someone Bubble [I will update this code but It exactly same myBubble snippet]
            }else {



                return someoneBubble

            }




    }
```

I'm using the parse-server sdk. My logic has two UITableViewCell because there are different position. One is right side other is left side.

So Function of tableView should check whether my Bubble or not.

It affect scrolling performance.

And also My code has lot of if statement to show the messages which is entered from currentUser.

Because If not shown the message immediately then user must waiting response until message is saved into the server or not.

Anyone advising me?

Comment: bro have to implemented bubble chat like as u did

Comment: i need help with it how will that increase with the help of text i want to increase the height